# Swiper Hash Navigation not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash, swiper.js

**EDIT** I've fixed a previous slash issue and have updated my question.

I'm trying to implement Swiper's hash navigation feature on an Angular.js site. [Here's the example they provide.](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/25-hash-navigation.html)

Once I've added the code, though, there appears to be a few problems.

1. Navigating to the new link doesn't work. It simply takes the user to the page without the hash. For instance, the user is taken to `www.example.com/gallery` instead of `www.example.com/gallery/#summer`
2. Navigating to `www.example.com/gallery/` will instead result in `www.example.com/gallery/#summer` being in the URL bar, but the page displayed is `www.example.com/gallery/`.

**My Code**

The swiper is initialized in scripts.js, like so:

```
//initialize swiper
var appendNumber = 0;
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationType: 'fraction',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 30,
    initialSlide: 1,
    //hash navigation attributes
    hashnav: true,
    hashnavWatchState: true,

});
```

After all php is loaded, here is what the swiper element looks like:

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper" style="transition-duration: 0ms;">
    <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" data-hash="the-producers-club">
        <img class="swiper_img" src="images/producersclub.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-next" data-hash="hummingbird-studios">
        <img class="swiper_img" src="images/CHI.png">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-hash="anthology-film-archives">
        <img class="swiper_img" src="images/large.jpg">
    </div>
    ....
```

Additionally, this script is called on the swiper when the php page is loaded in:

```
<script>
    swiper.update();
    //clear any pre-loaded slides
    swiper.removeAllSlides();

    //store images in swiper
    $(".modal_img").each(function(i,x) {
        //find venue name
        var closest_venue = ($(this).closest('.img_div').find('.screenings_p').text());
        //prepare string for hash navigation
        closest_venue = closest_venue.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    //add hash to URL
    swiper.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide" data-hash="' + closest_venue + '"><img class="swiper_img" src="' + $(this).attr("src") + '"/></div>');
})
....
```

I'm not sure exactly where I'm going wrong with this. Maybe the `swiper.update();` and `swiper.removeAllSlides();` are causing problems when the page loads?

I've crossposted this to the Swiper Forum [here](http://idangero.us/swiper/forum/#!/bugs-and-issues:swiper-hash-navigation-not).

Comment: try to update() when you finished to append slides

Comment: Did @As-If's answer solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solves your whole problem, but //hash navigation attributes should read:

```
  hashNavigation: {
    watchState: true,
  },
```